# <h:commandLink> not executing action in Safari Browser

Tags: css, jsf, safari, jsf-2.2, mojarra

I have a simple (ajaxified) commandLink in JSF that works well in all major browsers except for the latest Safari browser on iphone. To prevent double form submit, i use a common fragment that disables the button on ajax begin status:

```
<h:commandLink id="submit" action="#{ListingBean.searchListings}" value="Search">
    <f:ajax onevent="preventDblClick"/>
</h:commandLink>

function preventDblClick(data) {  

  switch (data.status) {
      case "begin":
          data.source.disabled = true;
          // data.source.className = 'blocked';
          break;
      case "complete":
          data.source.disabled = false;
          break;
  }    
}
```

The Problem is, that Safari does not submit the action because of the disabled state. I also tried to the set a css rule for the button to prevent multiple clicks on submit:

```
.blocked {
   pointer-events:none
}
```

but in that case, safari also does not submit the action.

**Update:**

There is a problem with the **return false** in the generated html:

```
<a id="submit" 
   onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,0,{'onevent':preventDblClick});return false">
     Search
</a>
```

Even if i completely remove the ajax-tag, the form won't submit and generated output looks like:

```
 <h:commandLink id="submit" action="#{ListingBean.searchListings}">
       Search
 </h:commandLink>

<a id="submit" 
  onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('form-search'),{'submit':'submit'},'');return false">
  Search
</a>
```

Why the `return false` is here?

Since more and more clients are using iphone/safari: How to solve this issue?

jsf version is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.14</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Tried a plain html example? I doubt it works there. Effectively making this a non-jsf issue. And I like the creativity of the solution, but you might run into some unspecified behaviour (=not defined in the standards)

Comment: yes, it works with a plain <a> or <input type="submit">. it is a jsf/mojarra issue. see updated question.

Comment: Firefox has the same 'return false;' right? And there it works? And if you don't have the `data.source.disabled=true` is the `return false' still there? And then it **does** work? That would be strange

Comment: the only problem is the generated "return false". its working in edge, ie11, firefox and chrome, but NOT safari. see updated question.

Comment: So without the css, no setting disabled etc, Safari still does not submit the form?

Comment: yes, true that!

Comment: How about waiting a little longer to disable the button? `onClick` is way too early for safari, but you can delay the disabling of the button. While this will almost inevitably result in using backing bean logic to toggle the button, you could step in a little earlier with the `f:event` tag and the `postValidate` event. It allows you to get a bit further, hopefully far enough for Safari to not ignore the submission.

Comment: @kolossus: javascript timeout?

Comment: @Kukeltje if you're referring to making the JS wait, I don't think that'll work because as long as the request stays on the client, the browser has full discretion on what to do with it. Letting it get past the browser is the key point here